# static instance is not shared between threads

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading, thread-safety

I am using a singleton class that suppose to have a single static instance as follows:

```
    private static ISingletonClass _instance = null;

    public static ISingletonClass GetInstance(string id = null)
    {
        if (_instance == null)
        {
            if (id != null)
            {
                _instance = new SingletonClass(id);
            }
            else
            {
                throw new NullReferenceException("id is missing!");
            }
        }

        if (id != null && _instance.Id != id)
        {
            _instance = new SingletonClass(id); // changing instance
        }

        return _instance;
    }
```

All other code in the class is not static (including the Id property).
Early in the run, when there is still a single, thread I initialize the singleton with some id, like so:

```
SingletonClass.GetInstance(<some_not_null_id>);
```

The _instance is set to not null (checked it).
Later I create a few threads to do some tasks, that need, among else, to read information from the SingletonClass (no writing).
According to any documentation I found, and answers in StackOverflow, the same instance should be available to all threads (I didn't use [ThreadStatic] or any other alike mechanism).

However, When trying to GetInstance() with no parameters from inside the threads I get NullException (the _instance member is Null).

I'm using .NET version 4.5, and working with VS2012.

Any ideas?

Comment: Side note: `NullReferenceException` is a reserved exception and thus you shouldn't throw it.

Comment: You get your nullexception, the one with "id is missing!" message?

Comment: You can use [`ArgumentNullException`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.argumentnullexception%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

Comment: Another side note: the way you implemented this it isn't a singleton anymore.

Comment: Your code has serious problem to consider it Singleton. When different Id get passed then it will create different object. It over write previously written instance reference.

Comment: @weston Yes, I get my exception. I checked, the _instance was null (it not, we wouldn't get to that poing in the code).

Comment: @dotnetstep yes I know that. That was the intention. There is a possibility in the program that we need to replace the instance. In anyway, we don't want two instances existing in the same time.

Comment: @Ziv But it IS possible to write code so that multiple instances exit at the same time. If I write `var s1 = SingletonClass.GetInstance("1"); var s2 = SingletonClass.GetInstance("2");` I have two different instances which exist at the same time.

Comment: In that case you have to maintain pool with Id because rightnow what you are doing is over write existing value.

Comment: Show your code to initialize the singleton and use the reader threads? Or prove the order of execution: add trace output (e.g. `Trace.WriteLine`)to the initialize code and reader thread code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, your assumption about the exception thrown is incorrect:

> NullException (the _instance member is Null).

The only `NullReferenceException` that would be thrown from your `GetInstance()` method is the one you throw yourself. Assuming you have no code anywhere else that resets the `_instance` value to `null`, the only place that method dereferences the `_instance` value is at a statement that cannot be reached without ensuring that `_instance` is initialized to some non-null value.

As for the broader problem, IMHO the biggest issue is that you have a poorly-defined problem, and a broken implementation.

Even ignoring the question of whether the "singleton" (it's not really a singleton, but for the sake of argument let's call it that for now) is ever changed, the initialization is not thread safe. You have the following potential race (assuming a single CPU core to make the illustration simple):

```
Thread 1                   Thread 2
--------                   --------
call GetInstance()
if (_instance == null)
--> preempted <--
                           call GetInstance()
                           if (_instance == null)
                           ...
                           _instance = new SingletonClass(id);
                           ...
                           return _instance;
                           --> preempted <--
if (_instance == null)
...
_instance = new SingletonClass(id);
...
return _instance;
```

As you can see in the above example, the way the code is written now, each thread could independently try to retrieve the instance, would see the current value as `null`, and would create a new instance object to be returned.

For a true singleton, the best way to implement this is with the `Lazy<T>` class:

```
private static readonly Lazy<SingletonClass> _instance =
   new Lazy<SingletonClass>(() => new SingletonClass());

public static SingletonClass Instance { get { return _instance.Value; } }
```

In this case, the `Lazy<T>` class handles all of the initialization work, including ensuring it's done in a thread-safe way.

In your case, where you do not have a true singleton, the above won't work. The `Lazy<T>` pattern only works when something is to be initialized just once, but you want to be able to change it on the fly. Given that, you need something more like this:

```
private static ISingletonClass _instance = null;
private static readonly object _lock = new object();

public static ISingletonClass GetInstance(string id = null)
{
    lock (_object)
    {
        if (_instance == null || (id != null && _instance.Id != id))
        {
            if (id == null)
            {
                throw new ArgumentNullException("id");
            }

            _instance = new SingletonClass(id);
        }

        return _instance;
    }
}
```

The above will ensure against threads initializing the field concurrently. They can race only to the lock, and then one thread is guaranteed to be the only one to initialize the object, assuming each thread passes the same value for `id`.

That said, that only fixes the basic thread-safety issue in your code. There are some bigger problems.

First, what do you expect the code to do if and when one thread retrieves the current instance, then some other thread changes the current instance before the first thread is done using the instance it retrieved? I'm not saying this is inherently broken, but it is at the very least very fragile, and you absolutely need to think about this scenario and decide for yourself what the right behavior should be in that case.

Second, this is a really fragile mutation of the singleton pattern. A true singleton will have a single object, allocated only once during the lifetime of the process. This ensures simplicity of design and predictability of behavior.

The implementation you have, will necessarily make it a lot harder to understand what the code is doing at any given point. It is practically guaranteed to add large amounts of time to some developer's day, either yours or someone else's, when some bug comes up and they are trying to track down the actual cause of the bug.

The fact that the instances of this class are tied to a string ID suggests that a better approach might be to maintain a `Dictionary<string, SingletonClass>` objects, requiring all callers to *always* specify the ID, and using that ID to retrieve (possibly initializing lazily of course) the object that thread needs at that moment.

I strongly recommend a different design. But at a minimum, if you decide you must go this direction, make sure that you have considered all of the various combinations of thread events, and not only decided what the correct behavior is in each given scenario, but added code to ensure any assumed constraints.

Comment: Thank you for comprehensive response. There are some clarifications i need to do: the _instance member IS null. That's a fact. I debugged it. The scenario you described is not possible in this case because, like I wrote originally, the instance is set successfully (debugged it) before threads are created. The threads are ONLY reading from the instance, not writing, or changing it. I do need to add some thread safty mechanism to the code, that art is true.

Comment: The fact that the `_instance` member is `null` doesn't mean that the `NullReferenceException` occurs while _using_ the `_instance` value (i.e. dereferencing it). If you simply meant that the value being `null` led to your own code throwing the `NullReferenceException` explicitly, then I misunderstood...my point was that the it's your own `throw new NullReferenceException...` that's causing the exception, not the actual use of the `_instance_ value.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you want a true singleton with a value you can update. This updating needs to be threadsafe. The creation should be a separate method from the getting.

```
private static readonly MyContainerClass _instance = new MyContainerClass(); //true singleton

private sealed class MyContainerClass //this is the singleton
{
   private ISingletonClass _value = null;

   public ISingletonClass Value //threadsafe access to your object
   {
      get { lock(this){ return _value; } }
   }

   public ISingletonClass CreateOrUpdateValue(string id) //threadsafe updating of your object
   {
      if (id==null) throw new ArgumentNullException("id is missing!");
      lock(this)
      {
        var instance = _instance.Value;

        if (instance == null || instance.Id != id)
          _instance.Value = new SingletonClass(id);

        return _instance.Value;
       }
    }
}

public static void CreateOrUpdateInstance(string id)
{
    _instance.CreateOrUpdateValue(id);
}

public static ISingletonClass GetInstance()
{
    var instance = _instance.Value;

    if (instance == null)
       throw new Exception("Instance has not been created");

    return _instance;
}

// this is like your original method if you really want it
public static ISingletonClass GetInstance(string id)
{
    return _instance.CreateOrUpdateValue(id);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the input, In general - you're correct. In this case, like I wrote, the instance is created BEFORE (serially) more threads are created. And the threads are NOT trying to replace the instance, only to get it (supplying no id). Still - it doesn't explain the problem - Why is the Static member not shared between threads?

Comment: Maybe because your code is not threadsafe. You have no locks.